# jwt how to verify access tokens?

Tags: express, jwt

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');)
require('dotenv').config()

const users = [
    {
        username: 'username',
        password: 'password'
    }
]


app.use(express.json())
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }))

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.send('body')
})

app.get('/login', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/Login.html')
})

app.post('/login', (req, res) => {
    const { username, password } = req.body
    const foundUser = users.find(user => {
        return user.username === username && user.password === password
    })

    if(foundUser) {
        const user = { username: foundUser.username, password: foundUser.password }
        const accessToken = jwt.sign(user, process.env.ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET_KEY)
        res.json({ accessToken: accessToken })
    } else {
        res.send('wrong username or password')
    }
})

app.get('/secret', (req, res) => {
        jwt.verify(req.body.accessToken, process.env.ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET_KEY, function(err, verify) {
        if(err) {
            res.send('denied')
        } else {
            res.send('granted')
        }
    })
})

app.listen(8080, () => {
    console.log('Listening on port 8080');
})
```

What I'm trying to do is that only logged in user can access what's in the secret route. But even if I'm logged in, it still says denied when I try to access the secret route. I'm very new to JWT. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

In your example, you're using `req.body` on a `GET` request. `GET` requests usually don't have a body, so it would be better to pass the token in the headers.

Your example can be changed to the following:

```js
app.get('/secret', (req, res) => {
        jwt.verify(req.headers.authorization, process.env.ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET_KEY, function(err, verify) {
        if(err) {
            res.send('denied')
        } else {
            res.send('granted')
        }
    })
})
```

Note the `req.headers.authorization`.